# How to use Many2many field in analytic view odoo

Tags: django, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I want to `tag_ids` field in statistical view.
I am using this type of query

```
SELECT min(pol.id) AS id,
        po.date_order::date AS date,
        pol.product_id AS product_id,
        pp.product_tmpl_id AS product_tmpl_id,
        po.company_id AS company_id,
        pt.product_brand_id AS product_brand_id,
        pt.categ_id AS categ_id,
        array_agg(p_tag.name) AS tag_id,
        'Point of Sale' AS origin,
        sum(pol.qty) AS qty
        FROM pos_order_line pol
        LEFT JOIN pos_order po ON po.id = pol.order_id
        LEFT JOIN product_product pp ON pp.id = pol.product_id
        LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id
        LEFT JOIN product_product_tag_rel pp_rel ON      pp_rel.product_id=pp.product_tmpl_id
        LEFT JOIN product_tag p_tag ON p_tag.id=pp_rel.tag_id
        LEFT JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.id=pt.product_brand_id
        WHERE po.state IN ('paid', 'done', 'invoiced')
        GROUP BY po.date_order, pol.product_id, pp.product_tmpl_id,
        po.company_id,pt.product_brand_id,pt.categ_id
```

Here I don't know how can i pass `tag_id` value to `many2many` field and set its filter? this query giving me result as i want, Buti Don't know how to display it on `statistical view` (analytic view)

Someone please tell me about it, I'll be very thankful